# Any better way to TRIM() after string.Split()?

Tags: c#, .net

Noticed some code such as

```
string[] ary = parms.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for( int i = 0; i < ary.Length; i++)
       ary[i] = ary[i].Trim();
```

works fine but wondering if there is a better way to do this in one step

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Gosh, silly me, expecting posted code to be compilable.

Comment: @Oded, I know, right? :)

Comment: you don't need the .ToCharArray()

Comment: @ConradFrix - to make it readable !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
string[] trimmedStrings = parms.Split(',')
                               .Select(s => s.Trim())
                               .Where(s => s != String.Empty)
                               .ToArray();
```

BTW, consider using generic typed list like `List<string>` rather than legacy arrays

```
IList<string> trimmedStrings = parms.Split(',')
                                    .Select(s => s.Trim())
                                    .Where(s => s != String.Empty)
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: your code does not do the same as OPs. E.g. this string ",,,,," has zero items in the array in OPs code and 6 in yours

Comment: "Legacy arrays"? `List` is NOT a replacement for an `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

Still 2 steps but without the loop

```
ary = ary.Select(str => str.Trim()).ToArray();
```

or

```
ary = ary.Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim())
                    .Where(str => str != string.Empty)
                    .ToArray();
```

To preserve the RemoveEmptyEntries behavior and also remove the items that are trimable

Answer (score 3):

This does it pretty neatly:

```
//This could be inlined to the row below if you wanted
Regex oRE = new Regex(@"\s*\,\s*");
string TestString = ",, test , TEST 2   ,Test3";
//This is really the line you're looking for - the rest of the code just sets up an example
string[] Results = oRE.Split(TestString.Trim());
foreach(string S in Results){
    Console.WriteLine(">>" + S + "<<");
}
```

as a one-liner:

```
string[] Results = new Regex(@"\s*\,\s*").Split(TestString.Trim());
```

Comment: You argument would be stronger if you removed your example code!  Making this a 1-liner would be nice.

Comment: As you wish. Updated and has both. =)